# How can I display stored procedure result set rows as columns in RDLC report?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

Below is the result set when I execute my stored procedure. Based on condition no.of  rows will

change. I am using typed dataset to store result set.

NSV     QTY     MONTH/YEAR

264.95 31248 APR/07

273.23 34044 MAY/07

230.96 22232 JUN/07

711.93 81992 JUL/07

427.23 50345 AUG/07

297.90 36961 SEP/07

495.37 43079 OCT/07

648.48 52428 NOV/07

622.06 46364 DEC/07

407.02 46461 JAN/08

605.45 73439 FEB/08

224.81 28121 MAR/08

308.12 33356 APR/08

328.22 35605 MAY/08

372.41 34107 JUN/08

I have to show above result in RDLC file Like below.

APR/07   MAY/07      JUN/07................JUN/08

264.95   273.23        230.96.................372.41

31248     34044        22232 ...............34107

Anyone  Please suggest me how to this requirement. Which control I have to use display data on

RDLC report? If I use table control,

is there any way to insert group on column like insert row group?

Regards,

N.SRIRAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of report that you want to create is known as Cross Tabulation - in SSRS/RDLC terms, it referred as **Matrix report** and you need to use Matrix control for that. Here are couple of links/tutorials that should get you started:

http://balavardhanreddy.over-blog.com/article-ssrs-matrix-control--43365341.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627441.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think Matrix table is the one you need...try to look at [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

Comment: thank you sir. If any doubts regarding this I will contact you sir.